# finding the correct entry in a C++ map using upper and lower bound

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to optimize my search in a `C++` `map` by using the `upper_bound` function:
The `map` is the variable `table`:

```
Foo& search(uint64 id, uint64 hash) {

   std::map<std::pair<uint64, uint64>, Foo>::const_iterator iter;

   std::pair<uint64, uint64> key(id, hash);
   iter = table.upper_bound(key);
   // for completeness I search for those elements which may be a match
   // they may fall into a different hash range

   for( ; iter != table.end() || iter != table.begin(); --iter ) {
         const Foo foo = iter->second;
         if(foo.id() == foo.first_hash() <= hash &&
            hash <= foo.second_hash()) {
            if( foo.state() == NORMAL) {
                   return foo;
            }
            else {
            // do something else
            }
        }
   }
```

However, when I execute the program it just hangs ... it looks like the search is not working at all, and I don't have the logs to tell me where the mistake was ... What am I doing wrong here? When I do a linear search, it works fine, but now when I try to improve the algorithm it fails ...

Comment: What is this expression `foo.id() == foo.first_hash() <= hash` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop condition

```
for( ; iter != table.end() || iter != table.begin(); --iter )
```

is the source of your infinite loop, as it is always true.

What you want to do, judging from the comments, is use a reverse iterator:

```
   map<int,int> a;
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      a[i] = 2*i;
   }
   auto it = a.upper_bound(5);
   reverse_iterator<map<int,int>::iterator> rev_it (it);
   for (; rev_it != a.rend(); rev_it++) {
      cout << rev_it->first;
   }
```

This will print `543210`.

Comment: true true ... but I'm losing the first element, dont I? because later I run the test cases, and some of them fail. However, I don't want to jump outside the for loop.

Comment: and I'm not incrementing until `table.end()` ... so I need to stop my for loop.

Comment: Maybe I'm not quite getting what you're doing. `upper_bound` returns an iterator to some element and then you want to iterate through the collection backwards until the beginning?

Comment: Yes. Suppose I have `'a','b', 'c', 'd'` on my map. And I look for `'b'` on the upper bound, and it returns me `'c'` right? However, because of the two hash keys, `'a', 'b'` would be candidates, so I have to check them.

Comment: @philippe Ah! Well, then I think I have a solution for you. Check my edit.